# Using custom attributes in "Server-Timing" HTTP response header

Tags: http, http-headers, server-timing

I'm adding support for the [Server-Timing](https://w3c.github.io/server-timing/) spec to my REST server,
but when I try to add custom attribute names, e.g. `db;dur=1.450;cnt=1;rows=3;sent=111;recv=3288`, above and beyond the `dur` and `desc` ones defined by the spec,
Google Chrome's devtools complains with warnings below in the Console.

```
ServerTiming: Unrecognized parameter "cnt".
ServerTiming: Unrecognized parameter "rows".
ServerTiming: Unrecognized parameter "sent".
ServerTiming: Unrecognized parameter "recv".
```

Am I supposed to stuff those extra info I'd like to return in the `desc` attribute?

Does anyone familiar with that spec have any insights? TIA, --DD

Comment: I ended up switching to `db;dur=1.450;desc="cnt:1 rows:3 sent:111 recv:3288"` instead, and Chrome is happy with that, showing the `desc` content on the Timing graph